# Scala Slick 3.0 Creating Table and then Inserting Rows

Tags: scala, slick

I have written this code to create a table and then insert few rows and print the number of rows inserted.

```
package com.example

import tables._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
    try {
      val people = TableQuery[Persons]
      val setupAction : DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
        people.schema.create
        )
      val setupFuture : Future[Unit] = db.run(setupAction)

      setupFuture.flatMap { _ => 
        val populateAction: DBIO[Option[Int]] = people ++= Seq(
            (1, "test1", "user1"),
            (2, "test2", "user2"),
            (3, "test3", "user3"),
            (4, "test4", "user4")
          )

        val populateFuture : Future[Option[Int]] = db.run(populateAction)

        populateFuture.map {results =>
          results.foreach(x => println(s"Number of rows inserted $x"))
        }
      }


    } finally db.close
  }
}
```

But when I run this code it fails with this exception

```
[info] Loading project definition from/Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest2/project
[info] Set current project to SlickTest2 (in build file:/Users/abhi/ScalaProjects/SlickTest2/)
[info] Running com.example.Hello RandomUtils warning: InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1253)
    at org.h2.util.RandomUtils.getSecureRandom(RandomUtils.java:50)
    at org.h2.util.RandomUtils.getSecureBytes(RandomUtils.java:139)
    at org.h2.engine.User.setUserPasswordHash(User.java:49)
```

Also, is there a way to avoid nesting of futures?

Comment: Are you sure `populateFuture` should be a `Future[Option[Int]]`?  Shouldn't it be `Future[Unit]`, as per the [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html#populating-the-database)?

Comment: Also, if you group together individual DBIO Actions and/or DBIO Sequences, you can avoid nesting flatMaps and maps using for comprehensions. Look at [these examples](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/dbio.html#transactions-and-pinned-sessions) for transactions. If you don't call `transactionally`at the end of the block, all actions will probably run like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because your program ran to the end and tried to `Future.cancel` the running database operations resulting in the `InterruptedException`.

You can `Await.result` on the `Future` from `populateFuture` before running `db.close`.

```
val result = populateFuture.map { results =>
  results.foreach(x => println(s"Number of rows inserted $x"))
}

Await.result(result, Duration.Inf)
```